# Need Silverlight template to reload

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datatemplate, master-detail

I am implementing a Master-Detail view (trying to use MVVM too). The master is a `ListBox` containing items of 5 different types (all formatted the same in the Master). The Detail has different form fields depending on the type of object selected in the Master. I am using a `DataTemplateSelector`, following this [CodeProject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92439/Silverlight-DataTemplateSelector). The correct template is selected based on the item selected in the `ListBox`, but there is a weird referencing issue.

If I go from one item of `Type1` in the master to another item of `Type1`, they will both be using the exact same template. This sounds good, but since it is the same reference any animations that were in progress in the first item will be showing in the second item. **How can I force the template to be applied individually so that animations in one view are separate from another view's use of the template?**

Code sample: (`ContentControl` presenting the Detail)

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CVS.View.CurrentItem}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <vms:MyTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                <vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template1>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:Type1View />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template1>
                <vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template2>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:Type2View />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template2>
                <vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template3>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:Type3View />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template3>
                <vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template4>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:Type4View />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template4>
                <vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template5>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:Type5View />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vms:MyTemplateSelector.Template5>
            </vms:MyTemplateSelector>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

**EDIT** -adding animation code

This animation code is executed on ComboBoxes through a behavior that acts upon the SelectionChanged event. Before running this, I check to see if the ComboBox is focused. This animation only happens if it is not focused, serving as a visual prompt that their previous selection had to be modified.

```
public void AnimateComboBox(ComboBox cbo)
{
    LinearGradientBrush myBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
    myBrush = Extensions.Clone<LinearGradientBrush>(cbo.BorderBrush as LinearGradientBrush);
    cbo.BorderBrush = myBrush;

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));

    foreach(GradientStop s in myBrush.GradientStops)
    {
        ColorAnimation anim = new ColorAnimation();
        anim.To = Colors.Red;
        anim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        anim.AutoReverse = true;
        anim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, s);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath(GradientStop.ColorProperty));

        sb.Children.Add(anim);
    }

    sb.Begin();
}
```

The Extensions.Clone comes from [Silverlight forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/1730/51694.aspx)

Comment: how have you defined your animations ?

Comment: @Cybermaxs sorry for the delay, I've added details on how my animations work.